# Java - Calling onclick method on webpage

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<tr id="data_11">
 <td colspan="7" class="row">
  <table class="table-inner">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="col-companyname" onclick="getDetails('11', 'ARBN=BN5321177&amp;CompName=A+ACTIVE+PLUMBING&amp;CompStat=DRGD&amp;Type=BUSN&amp;BusIDType=Number&amp;BusID=65057196&amp;=')" style="cursor:pointer;">A ACTIVE PLUMBING</td>
     <td class="col-companytype">Business Name</td>
     <td class="col-acn">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="col-abn">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="col-arbn">BN5321177</td>
     <td class="col-state">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="col-docimage">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_11" style="display:none;">
     <td colspan="7">
      <div id="div_11"></div></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table></td>
</tr>
```

I need to call the onclick method getDetails with the above given parameters and get the result. I tried doing this with jsoup but i couldnt get it to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you getdetails function is not getting called due to the parameters you are passing?

Comment: i think you misunderstood. The function works. I need a way to call the function via java code and extract information from the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Simple Answer*** : You can't call a javascript function from `Jsoup`. Jsoup is primarily meant for **extracting** and **manipulating** html data.

If you are interested in knowing  the response to the request made in `getDetails`, then you can simulate the same request in `Jsoup` and get the response. But, If its a business logic in javascript without any server interaction which changes the `DOM` then you can kiss-off your idea.